# Is that possible to see the list of Price Book Entries?

Tags: pricebook, product, pricebookentry

Is that possible to see the list of Price Book Entries? Does Salesforce have any standard functionality to display it? I tried to find a one but I ended with PriceBook and Products. Any thoughts please.

Comment: It's just a junction object. You can query for data. Ui would have to be built as no standard Ui for just that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be done using the Price Books Tab as shown below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished using an OOB report type: `Price Books with Products`

As you can see below, the available fields are the junction record: "Price Information" (the PBE) and the two parents: "Price Book Information" and "Product Information"

[image]

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. Now i understand there are several ways to accomplish this and your solutions are great. thanks again.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. You cannot see Price Book Entries with this Standard Report Type. You simply just need to create your own custom report type with Primary Object = Price Book Entry

Answer (score 1):

You can query for the pricebookentries in developer console -> query editor to see the list. But there is no standard tab available for this object.

Select id, pricebook2id, product2id from priceBookEntry